# yarn add chromedriver installs node_modules in the macos user directory

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

On macOS, in `/Users/Username/Documents/Projects/Projectname/`, running `sudo npm install --location=global yarn` in VS Code installs yarn.

In the same VS Code session, and in the same project directory, running `yarn add chromedriver` saves the node_modules files to `/Users/Username/node_modules/`

Restarting VSCode did not resolve this.

Google didn't have anything on this issue that I could see.

Help apprecaiated.